# Why is TAGS table setting persistent?

Tags: init-file, variables, ctags

I have in my startup init file a setting:

```
(setq tags-table-list (list "~/linux/TAGS"))
```

After using emacs and `TAGS` tables, I now want to change that to:

```
(setq tags-table-list (list "~/trunk/TAGS"))
```

However, the old linux `TAGS` are still being used in addition to the new trunk.

How can I expunge the old `TAGS` table?  I tried also deleting the buffer, but it just gets reloaded.

Comment: Checkout the `etags-select` and `etags-table` packages for fine control of TAGS files (yes, they work with ctags too).

Answer (score 3):

I encountered the similar problem weeks ago and found it was caused by `desktop.el`: once you enable `desktop-save-mode` in your init file, some global variables (specified by user option `desktop-globals-to-save`, which  includes `tags-table-list` by default) will be recovered and also **override you own setting in init file**. So if you was in the same situation, simply evaluate `(setq tags-table-list (list "~/trunk/TAGS"))` with <kbd>C-x C-e</kbd> **before** closing Emacs.

Comment: You can modify `desktop-globals-to-save` variable to NOT save `tags-file-name` and `tags-table-list`.

Comment: I'm facing this issue in a single invocation of Emacs, not due to restarting Emacs.

Comment: @kaushalmodi You're right, I agree your solution is more correct. I will consider to update the answer accordingly.

Comment: @WilliamKF I think I didn't misunderstand you on this, I was saying it might be due to `desktop-save-mode`.

Answer (score 1):

If you set tags-table-list, do not also set ‘tags-file-name’.

Moreover if your TAGS file name is "TAGS" you can only write the directory path:

```
(setq tags-table-list (list "~/trunk/"))
```